# The spine plugin for Phaser gives an error

Tags: phaser-framework, spine

I'm trying to upload the plugin to my project, tried all the methods, but nothing works. Returns an error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'createSkeleton')
    at initialize.set Skeleton (<anonymous>:1:290667)
    at new initialize (<anonymous>:1:289262)
    at Game Object Factory.spine (<anonymous>:1:54310)
    at MainWindow.create (MainWindow.js?21c4:53:27)
    at SceneManager.create (phaser.js?d4ef:89720:1)
    at SceneManager.loadComplete (phaser.js?d4ef:89632:1)
    at Loader Plug in.emit (phaser.js?d4ef:1908:1)
    at Leaderplugin.loadComplete (phaser.js?d4ef:192810:1)
    at Loader Plug in.file Process Complete (phaser.js?d4ef:192776:1)
    at t.on Process Complete (<anonymous>:1:25378)
```

I work on a local server. Here is a code example of how I connect everything
[image]

Comment: your code looks good, maybe your file path is wrong or the files have a wrong format _(or the phaser or plugin version are not correct)_. You could test this with the files (spine, atlas, ...) from the example here: https://phaser.io/examples/v3/view/spine/add-spine-object-to-group and here https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser3-examples/tree/master/public/assets/spine/3.8/demos

Comment: It seems like version incompatibility between spine files and spine plugin

Comment: Could you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the same problem I had. My spine JSON data were saved in an old format. You probably used DragonBones, which exports only version 3.3 spine data.

[Here](https://www.visionaire-studio.net/forum/thread/using-dragonbones-pro-free-software-to-create-bone-animations-for-visionaire-5/) are the details someone remarked what's wrong with the file. You have three options: (A) change the file manually each time you export it, (B) use the python file the dude provides there, or (C) make a function to change the data structure accordingly after they are loaded and before the skeleton is added to scene. (This is the way I went.)